# Casting a Select to get a property from .Last() in a collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a complex object with many children where I'm trying to only select a few properties from it and its children for displaying in a grid. The way the query was structured before with blindly tossing in every `.Include()` that was needed generated a SQL statement that is 1095 lines long.

I have no issue with getting single properties from a child object, however the one is the name of the last activity that was performed. Doing a `.Last().Name` on the collection tosses an Exception that it can't be converted to SQL. I'll make a basic example to help visualize (all FKs are actually set in my code, that's not the problem) :

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // just a dummy class everyone knows for illustration
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
}

public class Activity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class FooModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public string LastActivity { get; set; }
}
```

This is a basic example of the query I'm setting up:

```
public IEnumerable<FooModel> GetHomePageItems(IEnumerable<int> fooIds)
{
    return await context.Foos
                        .Where(f => fooIds.Contains(f.id))
                        .Select(f => new FooModel
                            {
                                Id = f.Id,
                                StreetName = f.Address.Street,
                                // here is the problem as it can't 
                                // convert this to SQL
                                LastActivity = f.Activities.Last().Name
                            })
                        .ToListAsync();
}
```

Is this something that cane be done, or do I have to pull everything in without the `LastActivity`, and then query for the activities with a GroupBy and get them that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try changing your query to:

```
var query = context.Foos
                .Where(f => fooIds.Contains(f.Id))
                .Select(f => new FooModel
                {
                    Id = f.Id,
                    StreetName = f.Address.Street,     
                    LastActivity = f.Activities.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault().Name
                }).ToListAsync();
```

That linq generates the following sql for Entity Framework version 6.1.3:

```
SELECT
    [Filter1].[Id1] AS [Id],
    [Filter1].[Street] AS [Street],
    [Limit1].[Name] AS [Name]
    FROM   (SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id1], [Extent2].[Street] AS [Street]
        FROM  [dbo].[Foos] AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Addresses] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Address_Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
        WHERE [Extent1].[Id] IN (1, 2, 3, 4) ) AS [Filter1]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Project1].[Name] AS [Name]
        FROM ( SELECT
            [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id],
            [Extent3].[Name] AS [Name]
            FROM [dbo].[Activities] AS [Extent3]
            WHERE [Filter1].[Id1] = [Extent3].[Foo_Id]
        )  AS [Project1]
        ORDER BY [Project1].[Id] DESC ) AS [Limit1]
```

Which might be enough for your project. On large amounts of data, though, you might have to switch to something faster, even probably to manual query using `.Sql()` method.

Entity Framework does not recognize `.LastOrDefault()` and `.Last()` methods, instead you should use `.FirstOrDefault()` or `.First()` methods coupled with `OrderBy()` or `OrderByDescending()`.

Comment: Excellent! I'll give that a try in the morning.

Comment: Huzzah! It worked. Thank you, sir. In the panic at the end of the day yesterday, I had forgotten about making it more "verbose" like that. (For the record, this took the query down to 54 lines.)